Увеличьте каждое число словаря в два раза
Подскажите пожалуйста, как увеличить каждое число в словаре в два раза.
    digits = {
     'a': 1,
     'b': 2,
     'c': 3,
     'd': 4,
}

n = digits.values()
for i in n:
     i = n * 2
print(i)

Пробовал кодить, чёт пока не вышло

digits = {k: 2 * v for k, v in digits.items()}

Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы. Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

MBo, понял принял

У вас дважды потеряна связь со словарём.

.values() делает список значений словаря, он уже не имеет обратной связи со словарём, что бы вы с этим списком не делали.
for i in n: переменная i не имеет обратной связи с коллекцией n, что бы вы не делали с этой переменной

Правильное изменение значений словаря должно выглядеть так:
for key in digits:
    digits[key] = ...


1 - на самом деле не потеряна: a = {'a': 1}; v = a.values(); a.clear(); a['b'] = 2; print([x for x in v])

(а for _ in a.values(): a.clear() ещё и RuntimeError плюнет)

@andreymal Ну конечно я имел в виду обратную связь, я это даже словами написал, не прикапывайтесь )  И через i и через n ничего со списком digits сделать нельзя.

Связь-то всё равно есть, просто только на чтение
